# running individual packages from eclipse (not running on the server)

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

Currently, on the project I'm working on we're running jboss as the server. All code in the repository branch is setup to run on the jboss server. However, my work doesn't require that I run the server yet - it's just a Java class I need to test.

How do I run my code as a java project and not as Jboss?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it has an appropriate `main` method, in the editor for the class, you can just right-click, select "Run As" then "Java Application" (or use the appropriate shortcut, e.g. Alt-Shift-X J).

Alternatively, go to the "Run" button, click on the drop down arrow and go to "Run Configurations" where you can create a new configuration.